# super scripts in excel sheet not coming in dataset in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, dataset, oledb

im trying to import excel sheet values to text box. in dataset super script values not coming . like x to the power of 2 . its coming as x2 in dataset 
i need to get super scripts as it is in data set

below is the code to get values from excel

```
                string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path1 + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
                //Create Connection to Excel work book
                OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [Answer],[Question],[Option1],[Option2],[Option3],[Option4],[Solution] from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
```

kindly check the screen shot

http://postimg.org/image/wbb6bv1d5/

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that the superscripting is not part of the cell's *value*, it is part of the cell's *formatting*.

Your code extracts the cell's values which are, in effect, just simple strings and then you store these strings in your `DataSet`.

You therefore have 2 issues:

1. You need to work out how you are going to represent, store and use this "*formatted* text" in your code
2. You need to work out how to extract this extra formatting information from the excel spreadsheet

I see 3 possible approaches to resolve this. Only you will know which fits best within your 'big picture' based on what you are trying to achieve and how this fits in with your other code but, based on what I know, these are roughly in order of preference:

1. Those formatted "strings" with superscripts look awfully like numbers expressed in scientific notation to me! If that is the case you would be well  advised to store them as such in both the Excel spreadsheet and within your code if at all possible. Doing this means that you then have those floating point numbers stored in your `DataSet` after the import. You could then feasibly display them in whichiver way you need when you come to use them from your `DataSet`
2. Plan B would be to extract the formatting information from the Excel worksheet so you can replicate this within your code. You have 2 problems to solve with this approach - The first is that you need to use a different means to export the data from your Excel file, the second is you need some suitable object to store a representation of the formatted text with the superscript element. These are acheivable (if a little kludgy) using a library like [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/). For example, using html to represent the string I could do something like this (within a suitable loop to loop through all the excel rows you want to export):

   ```
   using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\superscriptExample.xlsx")))
   {
       var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();


       ExcelRichTextCollection richText = ws.Cells[1, 1].RichText;
       string htmlString = "";
       foreach (var part in richText)
       {
           if (part.VerticalAlign == ExcelVerticalAlignmentFont.Superscript)
           {
               htmlString += "<sup>" + part.Text + "</sup>";
           }
           else
           {
               htmlString += part.Text;
           }
       }

   }
   ```
3. Plan C: If you are certain that all your strings are of the format "xxxxxx10ssN" where ss is the part to be in superscript you could feasibly just parse each one into an html element (or whatever other object you are using to represent the formatted text) with something like the following:

   ```
   static string GetHtmlRepresentation(string inputTxt)
       {
           int indexOf10 = inputTxt.IndexOf("10");
           int indexOfN = inputTxt.IndexOf("N", indexOf10);
           string beforeSupPart = inputTxt.Substring(0, indexOf10 + 2);
           string supPart = inputTxt.Substring(indexOf10 + 2, indexOfN - (indexOf10 + 2));
           string afterSup = inputTxt.Substring(indexOfN, inputTxt.Length - indexOfN);

           return beforeSupPart + "<sup>" + supPart + "</sup>" + afterSup;
       }
   ```

   This option is horribly ugly but if you just need a bit of a quick and dirty 'get the job done' solution then maybe you want to look at it.

Comment: hello @Stewart_R . i need sub scripts also , can u edit ur solution  which can work for both  super script and sub script.Thanks

Comment: Was there a particular difficulty converting to subscript? You can use the html tag `<sub>` rather than `<sup>` and the `part.VerticalAlign == ExcelVerticalAlignmentFont.Subscript`.